# Badge styling seems not to be working on Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, badge

moved from Vaadin 22 to 23 and badge styling seems not be working as expected.

Loading resources pretty much the same way:

```
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js")
@CssImport(include = "lumo-badge", value = "./styles/empty.css")
public class SomeClass...
...
envBadge.getElement().getThemeList().add("badge success");
```

@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js do exists in node_modules dir...

Any idea? According to documentation, it seems right, as in version 22...

Thanks

Comment: Did you import the styles in `theme.json` as described in the docs https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/badge?

Comment: Yeah, tried that too with no luck. Also, in version 22 that's present in docs too and while not using it, it works...

Comment: It could be a bug, but I cannot replicate it. If you can, please open a ticket with the minimal steps to reproduce the issue at https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components.

Comment: Same problem in Vaadin 24.1 here. The "badge" annotation in the theme.json file is already added by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. `@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js")` and
`@CssImport(include = "lumo-badge", value = "./styles/empty.css")` annotations worked fine with latest 22 version but after upgrading to 23 version, badge styles stop working.
But I manage to resolve issue. I removed those annotations from my Badge class, created `frontend/themes/common-theme/theme.json` file with content

```
{
  "lumoImports": ["badge"]
}
```

and finally I added `@Theme("common-theme")` into my app configurator

```
@Theme("common-theme")
public class AppConfigurator implements AppShellConfigurator {
}
```

Comment: Vaadin should put this example in their migration guide

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vaadin 14.10.1 and I was facing the same issue when I used a badge in my application. I was able to resolve this issue by creating a CSS file /frontend/styles/vaadin-badge.css from the style defined in GitHub (https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/blob/v1.6.1/badge.html) and adding the following annotation in the main class.

```
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js")
@CssImport(include = "lumo-badge", value = "./styles/vaadin-badge.css")
```